# Load youtube page via YQL with authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, youtube, yql

Since you can't iframe youtube, I'd like to display this page: https://www.youtube.com/comments (this page shows all the comments)

The YT API only allows me to request video-specific comments.

I'm already logged in on youtube, so how can I request that page WITH my authentication cookie/details via the YQL framework?

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

select * from html where url="https://www.youtube.com/comments"

It returns:

```
{
 "query": {
 "count": 0,
 "created": "2014-11-07T10:05:17Z",
 "lang": "nl-NL",
 "results": null
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going through a [blog post](http://stevezeidner.com/twitter-api-v1-1-front-end-access-with-yql/) that addresses this issue of getting OAuth to work with YQL.

It suggests storing your credentials in a textfile whose URL is known to you like so [`foo.txt`]:

```
 env 'http://datatables.org/alltables.env';
 set oauth_consumer_key = "yourConsumerKey" on twitter;
 set oauth_consumer_secret = "yourConsumerSecret" on twitter;
 set oauth_token = "OauthToken" on twitter;
 set oauth_token_secret = "OauthTokenSecret" on twitter;
```

Now you can use `yql.storage.admin` to 'embed' this key-value pairs for use with your YQL query. From the [official documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-storage-new-records.html):

> YQL now provides two Open Data Tables, yql.storage and yql.storage.admin, that allow you to store and work with data using YQL itself. These default tables are available in the YQL console under the "yql" category. You interact with these Open Data Tables using the same keywords used with other YQL statements: namely SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE.

So you would execute this YQL query:

```
insert into yql.storage.admin (name,url) values ("keys","PathTofoo.txt");
```

This creates an environment file for your queries. So the next time you make a call to https://www.youtube.com/comments, these environment variables will be taken into account.

There is a major caveat to this though, anyone can use the env link to execute read requests, but they don’t directly have access to your keys. It's always better to this from the server side whenever possible. Hope it gets you started in the right direction.